# Concatenating two strings in a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

The title is a bit misleading as I'm not quite clever enough to come up with an appropriate header that describes exactly what I'm trying to accomplish, so I apologize for that. Hopefully I can compensate for this with the description below.

I'm working on an exercise from a book that requires a bit of cleanup before I can perform any other operations. I have a list of lists in which elements in *some*, not all, of these lists require an update through concatenation (or perhaps other, more efficient, means if people suggest them). To better explain, here is a slice from that list of lists:

```
[['e726fb69de83a3ec', 'General_Mobile', 'Android', 'unknown', '0'], 
['1b8978f618d59eef', 'General_Mobile', 'iOS', 'unknown', '0'], 
['8ee82ed6c2c5af59', 'General_Desktop', 'Windows', 'XP', 'male', '29'], 
['d0fff09ca1829e65', 'General_Mobile', 'Android', 'female', '48'], 
['3126deccaae39ea1', 'General_Desktop', 'Windows', 'XP', 'male', '24'], 
['6778d882a1f59b5b', 'General_Mobile', 'iOS', 'female', '25']]
```

The elements in each list correspond to a userID, device, OS, sex and provinceID, respectively. If you take a look at the third and fifth lists, this is where my dilemma arises--you'll notice that 'Windows' and 'XP' are separate strings where they should instead be a single string, i.e., just 'Windows XP', so that these two strings appear in their respective lists amongst the others as:

```
['8ee82ed6c2c5af59', 'General_Desktop', 'Windows XP', 'male', '29']
['3126deccaae39ea1', 'General_Desktop', 'Windows XP', 'male', '24']
```

The remaining lists above are absolved from this problem, so there is no need to modify them.

So, I've tried to develop some reasonable means by which I can join the two strings in lists that have such a separation (I have other lists not shown in the sample above that are displayed similarly, e.g., 'Windows' '7' instead of 'Windows 7'), but I've yet to do so. Is there a 'clean' way of doing this or would I have to resort to creating a loop that removes these strings and then inserts a concatenation of the two?

Comment: Is `'Android'` and `'unknown'` supposed to be concatenated to `'Android unknown'` ?

Comment: @JohnColeman I was guessing that was unknown gender...

Comment: Is the example list you provide your actual source data or is it post any processing that you've done?

Comment: if you are reading a CSV file, you should split based on the delimiter OR, you need to change the format of `Windows XP` to `Windows_XP`. Else there is no generic way to achieve this even though you may make a work around

Comment: @JonClements I didn't pick up at first that the sublists have differing lengths.

Comment: @JohnColeman I have a strong suspicion this isn't the OP's starting data and that no correction is actually necessary if it's read correctly to start with... :)

Comment: @JonClements You are probably correct. Solutions that make semantic distinctions based on lengths of lists (5 vs. 6) are intrinsically fragile.

Comment: @JonClements This data was imported from a .txt from accompanying source code for the book I'm using.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a simple list comprehension:

```
>>> data = [['e726fb69de83a3ec', 'General_Mobile', 'Android', 'unknown', '0'],
['1b8978f618d59eef', 'General_Mobile', 'iOS', 'unknown', '0'],
['8ee82ed6c2c5af59', 'General_Desktop', 'Windows', 'XP', 'male', '29'],
['d0fff09ca1829e65', 'General_Mobile', 'Android', 'female', '48'],
['3126deccaae39ea1', 'General_Desktop', 'Windows', 'XP', 'male', '24'],
['6778d882a1f59b5b', 'General_Mobile', 'iOS', 'female', '25']]
```

and then:

```
>>> [item if len(item) == 5 else item[:2] + [' '.join(item[2:4])] + item[4:] for item in data]
[['e726fb69de83a3ec', 'General_Mobile', 'Android', 'unknown', '0'], ['1b8978f618d59eef', 'General_Mobile', 'iOS', 'unknown', '0'], ['8ee82ed6c2c5af59', 'General_Desktop', 'Windows XP', 'male', '29'], ['d0fff09ca1829e65', 'General_Mobile', 'Android', 'female', '48'], ['3126deccaae39ea1', 'General_Desktop', 'Windows XP', 'male', '24'], ['6778d882a1f59b5b', 'General_Mobile', 'iOS', 'female', '25']]
```

Comment: I'd also venture that if you can say the first and last two columns are fine, then you can make this a bit more general by using: `[el[:2] + [' '.join(el[2:-2])] + el[-2:] for el in data]` (at least then you're not dealing with absolute offsets, and if you can narrow it down that the iffy area is only between known good areas... then the code becomes simpler and the length check can be removed)

Answer (score 0):

For your specific case, if it's always the platform that is potentially the issue, you could check if the list has too many items, and if so, combine the items on the 2nd and 3rd indices. If you need a broader solution though, please clarify in your problem.

```
NUM_ITEMS_PER_LIST = 5
lists = [
    ['e726fb69de83a3ec', 'General_Mobile', 'Android', 'unknown', '0'],
    ['1b8978f618d59eef', 'General_Mobile', 'iOS', 'unknown', '0'],
    ['8ee82ed6c2c5af59', 'General_Desktop', 'Windows', 'XP', 'male', '29'],
    ['d0fff09ca1829e65', 'General_Mobile', 'Android', 'female', '48'],
    ['3126deccaae39ea1', 'General_Desktop', 'Windows', 'XP', 'male', '24'],
    ['6778d882a1f59b5b', 'General_Mobile', 'iOS', 'female', '25']
]

for l in lists:
    if len(l) > NUM_ITEMS_PER_LIST:
        l[2] = '{} {}'.format(l[2], l[3])
        del l[3]

print(lists)
```

**Output**:

```
[
    ['e726fb69de83a3ec', 'General_Mobile', 'Android', 'unknown', '0'],
    ['1b8978f618d59eef', 'General_Mobile', 'iOS', 'unknown', '0'],
    ['8ee82ed6c2c5af59', 'General_Desktop', 'Windows XP', 'male', '29'],
    ['d0fff09ca1829e65', 'General_Mobile', 'Android', 'female', '48'],
    ['3126deccaae39ea1', 'General_Desktop', 'Windows XP', 'male', '24'],
    ['6778d882a1f59b5b', 'General_Mobile', 'iOS', 'female', '25']
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `map`:

```
mylist = [['e726fb69de83a3ec', 'General_Mobile', 'Android', 'unknown', '0'], ['1b8978f618d59eef', 'General_Mobile', 'iOS', 'unknown', '0'], ['8ee82ed6c2c5af59', 'General_Desktop', 'Windows', 'XP', 'male', '29'], ['d0fff09ca1829e65', 'General_Mobile', 'Android', 'female', '48'], ['3126deccaae39ea1', 'General_Desktop', 'Windows', 'XP', 'male', '24'], ['6778d882a1f59b5b', 'General_Mobile', 'iOS', 'female', '25']]

map(lambda x: x[:2]+[" ".join(x[2:4])]+x[4:] if len(x) == 6 else x, mylist)
```

Output:

```
[['e726fb69de83a3ec', 'General_Mobile', 'Android', 'unknown', '0'],
 ['1b8978f618d59eef', 'General_Mobile', 'iOS', 'unknown', '0'],
 ['8ee82ed6c2c5af59', 'General_Desktop', 'Windows XP', 'male', '29'],
 ['d0fff09ca1829e65', 'General_Mobile', 'Android', 'female', '48'],
 ['3126deccaae39ea1', 'General_Desktop', 'Windows XP', 'male', '24'],
 ['6778d882a1f59b5b', 'General_Mobile', 'iOS', 'female', '25']]
```